# Editing a single line in a cpp file leads to whole project rebuild

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qmake

SO!

I have a usual ~50 files c++ project, created in QtCreator. Everything compiles fine, except for a single .cpp file: when I edit even a single line inside of it, compilation proceeds for whole project, which takes a lot of time. Editing other files doesn't have such behavior: only those edited are recompiled before linking.

This .cpp is not "#include"'d into anything, of course.

What could be the reason for such behavior?

I can't post any example because I have no idea what can be the cause of it. Also, I can't post it due to NDA.

Comment: Try to create a [mre]. Make a copy of your project, then prune the copy down to 2 source files: one that compiles normally and one that causes both files to compile. Then trim those files down to minimal contents. (The "normal" file might end up being something like `void foo() {}`.) If you get a true [mre], it will likely be simplified to the point where the NDA no longer applies (or to the point where the cause is so obvious that you see it).

Comment: The list of possible reasons is many. I'm afraid that you'll have to figure it out by yourself, since only you have access to all the files and configurations.